# ingress domain based routing is not working in browser but I'm able to curl the URL on ingress controller pod successfully

Tags: reverse-proxy, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

**I have installed the ingress controller using the link :**
https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke

which is up and running

```
NAME TYPE CLUSTER-I EXTERNAL-IP PORT(S)

nginx-ingress-controller LoadBalancer   X.X.X.X   X.X.X.X1   80:123/TCP,443:456/TCP
```

After that I have installed and exposed the application as nodePort, bot app up and running.

**Ingress Rules are defined as mentioned in attachment :**

[image]

To very I did exec in inginx-controller pod and test the followings:

Tests: 1

Input :  curl localhost

Output : default backend - 404

Tests: 2

Input :  curl localhost -H 'Host:foo.com'

Output : app working properly

Tests: 3

Input :  curl localhost -H 'Host:faa.com'

Output : app working properly

Tests: 4 on Browser Chrome

- Input : foo.com
- Input : faa.com

Output : default backend - 404

**I'm  not able to figureout where am I missing to recheck**

Please support me for for the same.

Comment: Please have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page

Comment: @kartik Where did you run those curl commands? I mean what is localhost?

Comment: Thanks for your response Peter!!
I have run the command inside the kubernetes cluster container. 
Do you want further info, feel free to ask!!

Answer (score 0):

Upon looking at your YAML file, I can see that you do not have a 'default backend' in the Ingress service. The 'default backend' will define the rules to take if the page results in an error 404.

The ‘default backend’ is different from the `backend` under the `path`.
The default backend has to be right under the `spec`.

For more information on the default backend, you may read through the [k8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#types-of-ingress)

This is the how you should define a default backend in your YAML file.

```
spec:
   backend:
```

For the same reason, it is not working on the chrome browser. There is no 'default backend'.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but somebody might have similar situation.

In my case, problem was next:

When executing curl command:

```
curl http://<ip-address>:<k8s-svc-port> -H 'Host:foo.com'
```

HTTP request looks something like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.com
User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
Accept: */*
```

When executing in browser, http request looks something like this:
[firefox http request example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vltB9.png)

```
Host: foo.com:32009
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
...
```

And that's the difference, because haproxy ingress controller looks for host field of http request. In this case, 
 - curl sets header **Host:foo.com** 
 - browser sets header **Host:foo.com:32009**, which is not recognized by haproxy 
 
(haproxy expects **foo.com** and gets **foo.com:32009**)

So, ingress controller works fine, it's the browsers http request that's making problem.

I hope this can be helpful.

Comment: So how did you finally get it working for the browser?

Comment: @RakeshGuha Since this is test environment for me, i just did next: installed nginx on my local machine, setup record in /etc/hosts for foo.com => 127.0.0.1 and in nginx proxied request from 127.0.0.1:80 to <real_ip>:<k8s-svc-port>